# Match rows in one data frame to another based on key column values pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames (A and B) representing two sides of a transaction with m and n rows in each respectively. There are a few key columns which uniquely identify these transactions. I need to find row_in_A and row_in_B such that these key columns are the equal for the two, the remaining columns don't matter. I then need to remove these rows from the respective dfs.

Before:

In A:

```
Seller | Buyer | Side A
----------------------
  X    |   Y   | True
  C    |   D   | True
```

In B:

```
Seller | Buyer | Side B
----------------------
  X    |   Y   | True
```

Assuming the key columns are only Seller and Buyer, these rows should be matched and subsequently deleted from A and B. The columns can/will contain duplicate entries in both dfs.

After:

```
Seller | Buyer | Side A
----------------------
  C    |   D   | True
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [`MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html) from `Seller` and `Buyer` columns, then use [`MultiIndex.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21.1/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.isin.html) to create a boolean mask, use this mask to filter the rows.:

```
i1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df1['Seller'], df1['Buyer']])
i2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df2['Seller'], df2['Buyer']])

df1, df2 = df1[~i1.isin(i2)], df2[~i2.isin(i1)]
```

Similar idea using [`DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
i1 = df1.set_index(['Seller', 'Buyer']).index
i2 = df2.set_index(['Seller', 'Buyer']).index

df1, df2 = df1[~i1.isin(i2)], df2[~i2.isin(i1)]
```

Result:

```
print(df1)
  Seller Buyer  Side A
1      C     D    True
```